# Cache is out of sync, can't x-ref a package file

Tags: chef-infra, apt-get

When installing packages via CHEF on Amazon EC2 instance I got the following error:

```
Cache is out of sync, can't x-ref a package file
```

on following lines:

```
%w{htop sysstat bwm-ng needrestart debian-goodies}.each do |pkg|
  package pkg
end
```

I did a lot bit of googling but no answer and I have now clue what this means and more important how to prevent it :(

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'apt_package[htop]'
================================================================================

Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '100'
---- Begin output of apt-cache policy htop ----
STDOUT: htop:
Installed: 2.0.1-1ubuntu1
Candidate: 2.0.1-1ubuntu1
Version table:
*** 2.0.1-1ubuntu1 500
500 http://eu-central-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
STDERR: E: Cache is out of sync, can't x-ref a package file
---- End output of apt-cache policy htop ----
Ran apt-cache policy htop returned 100

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/chef/runs/0c236d60-212c-4e9a-a6c1-fb8af8960425/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/k2go-common/recipes/setup.rb

20:   package pkg
21: end

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/chef/runs/0c236d60-212c-4e9a-a6c1-fb8af8960425/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/k2go-common/recipes/setup.rb:20:in `block in from_file'

apt_package("htop") do
package_name "htop"
action [:install]
retries 0
retry_delay 2
default_guard_interpreter :default
declared_type :package
cookbook_name "k2go-common"
recipe_name "setup"
end

Platform:
---------
x86_64-linux

[2017-05-17T19:01:36+02:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
[2017-05-17T19:01:36+02:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2017-05-17T19:01:36+02:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2017-05-17T19:01:36+02:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/runs/0c236d60-212c-4e9a-a6c1-fb8af8960425/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2017-05-17T19:01:36+02:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2017-05-17T19:01:36+02:00] ERROR: apt_package[htop] (k2go-common::setup line 20) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '100'
---- Begin output of apt-cache policy htop ----
STDOUT: htop:
Installed: 2.0.1-1ubuntu1
Candidate: 2.0.1-1ubuntu1
Version table:
*** 2.0.1-1ubuntu1 500
500 http://eu-central-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
STDERR: E: Cache is out of sync, can't x-ref a package file
---- End output of apt-cache policy htop ----
Ran apt-cache policy htop returned 100
[2017-05-17T19:01:36+02:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

What I see in the log is that http://eu-central-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu returned 500 status code so Ubuntu could have some sort of (short) outage? I believe we could add/increase retries which is 0 by default?

Comment: can you please update a bit more log trace?

Comment: I have updated log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it looks to temporary outage at ubuntu sources, therefore increasing retries option will enable the resource to catch exceptions and retry again, i.e,

```
%w{htop sysstat bwm-ng needrestart debian-goodies}.each do |pkg|
  package pkg do
    retries 5
  end
end
```

But it is always good to run `apt-get update` on ubuntu before installing the packages because that actually retrieves information about what packages can be installed, including what updates to currently installed packages packages are available, from Internet sources.

For that you can look at using:

https://docs.chef.io/resource_apt_update.html

https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/apt

Answer (score 1):

You probably need an `apt-get update` which you can do using an `apt_update` resource.